# Flutter: Random a list of colors

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

My goal is to generate multiple Stickynote with different color,
I already build a list of six different colors.
I want to put them shuffle on the card.

ERROR

> "message": "The instance member 'color' can't be accessed in an initializer.\nTry replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression",

Here is the code:

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Sticky {
  final String note;
  List color = [
    const Color(0xffB85252),
    const Color(0xffB4C6A6),
    const Color(0xffF4ABC4),
    const Color(0xff346751),
    const Color(0xffFFC947),
    const Color(0xff3282B8),
  ];

  var colorItem = (color.toList()..shuffle()).first;

  Sticky({required this.note, required this.color});
}

class StickyNote extends StatefulWidget {
  final color;
  final String note;
  const StickyNote({Key? key, this.color, required this.note})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StickyNoteState createState() => _StickyNoteState();
}

class _StickyNoteState extends State<StickyNote> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      color: Sticky.colorItem,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why, you are using `required this.color` and initializing at the same time?

Comment: The message is clear you didn't initialize the Sticky instance, wouldn't it be better to make a method inside statefull?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a very bad dart code, without any sense to me but I think it is only part of your code.

There is a couple of errors here, that I will summarize below, and also I'm assuming that this code is partial and there is no sense in the usage that you are doing in your example:

- final color is not null, and it `required`

```dart
     class StickyNote extends StatefulWidget {
      final Color color;
      final String note;
      const StickyNote({Key? key, required this.color, required this.note})
          : super(key: key);
```

You are using the class Sticky as a static class, but any of the propriety is static.

A workable solution is the following one

```dart
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class Sticky {
  final String note;
  static List color = [
    const Color(0xffB85252),
    const Color(0xffB4C6A6),
    const Color(0xffF4ABC4),
    const Color(0xff346751),
    const Color(0xffFFC947),
    const Color(0xff3282B8),
  ];

  Sticky({required this.note});
  
  static Color getColorItem() => (color.toList()..shuffle()).first;
}

class StickyNote extends StatefulWidget {
  final Color color;
  final String note;
  const StickyNote({Key? key, required this.color, required this.note})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StickyNoteState createState() => _StickyNoteState();
}

class _StickyNoteState extends State<StickyNote> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      color: Sticky.colorItem(),
    );
  }
}
```

In addition, with this code there is a little bit more sense if your colors didn't change, otherwise, you need to use the object and not the class

Comment: I am a novice,
I removed the riquired
and I initialize the list in the main class.
advice is important to me.  ...thank you.

Comment: all we start somewhere :) remember to mark the answer as correct if it solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this:

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

class StickyColors {
 static final List colors = [
    const Color(0xffB85252),
    const Color(0xffB4C6A6),
    const Color(0xffF4ABC4),
    const Color(0xff346751),
    const Color(0xffFFC947),
    const Color(0xff3282B8),
  ];
}

class StickyNote extends StatefulWidget {
  final String note;
  const StickyNote({Key? key, required this.note})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StickyNoteState createState() => _StickyNoteState();
}

class _StickyNoteState extends State<StickyNote> {

 final _random = Random();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 300,
      height: 300,
      color: StickyColors.colors[_random.nextInt(6)],
    );
  }
}
```

I did not actually test it, but I have something similar in my app.

Comment: IMO the API is not good here, you can hide the logic of the getColor() inside one method and forget it. With this color, if you change the logic inside the StickyColor you need to change also the view. And also, you don't need the stateful widget here

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo , I agree about the Statefulwidget, it is not necessary. This was just because the original code used it.

Comment: Use colors.length instead of static 6  StickyColors.colors[_random.nextInt(colors.length)],

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a random sticky note color without any state logic. You can also convert it to one statelesswidget which can be reused easily:

```
class StickNote extends StatelessWidget {

final List colors = [
   const Color(0xffB85252),
   const Color(0xffB4C6A6),
   const Color(0xffF4ABC4),
   const Color(0xff346751),
   const Color(0xffFFC947),
   const Color(0xff3282B8),
];

final _random = Random();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    color: colors[_random.nextInt(6)],
  );
 }
}
```